# Can a python dictionary datatype contain a key which is a list element and value which is an array element

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I am new to python sorry if I have made any errors

I have a data like this

```
ENSG1   1:24    2:56    3:47    4:68    5:89
ENSG2   1:25    2:57    3:48    4:69    5:90
ENSG3   1:26    2:58    3:49    4:70    5:91
```

The first column is the {key} and the remaining columns will be the {values} in the key -> value pair of a dictionary element.

Is this possible in python??

Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Yes.  Probably.  Are these strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above answers  and suggestions from many different sites I would like to present my answer to the question I posted

```
import numpy as np
keys = np.array(("key1","key2","key3"))
values = np.array([['20','30','40'],['56','76','80',],['57','70','89']])
d = {}
for k in set(keys):
    d[k] = values[k==keys]
print d
```

Result:

```
{'key3': array([['57', '70', '89']],
      dtype='|S2')}
{'key3': array([['57', '70', '89']],
      dtype='|S2'), 'key2': array([['56', '76', '80']],
      dtype='|S2')}
{'key3': array([['57', '70', '89']],
      dtype='|S2'), 'key2': array([['56', '76', '80']],
      dtype='|S2'), 'key1': array([['20', '30', '40']],
      dtype='|S2')}
```

Thanks for the support rendered by all

Comment: It's almost like you answered a totally different question then you asked.

Comment: @Delirious Lettuce I have converted my list into array and used that as key for my dictionary.My question was can a list be used as a key so I have found a way to do it.Please suggest how well can I improve my answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to correspond to the sample data you gave in your original question. I took your sample data and split it as you requested. You accepted it as the correct answer and then re-confirmed it was correct by saying `"The end result is what I actually I want"`. Now you seem to have decided to accept your own answer to a different question with different sample data altogether.

Comment: Sorry may be I'm wrong the end result given by you was perfect but the code didn't work correctly for me so had to change. At the end of the day I got what I wanted for further analysis

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> test = """\
... ENSG1   1:24    2:56    3:47    4:68    5:89
... ENSG2   1:25    2:57    3:48    4:69    5:90
... ENSG3   1:26    2:58    3:49    4:70    5:91"""
>>> result = {}
>>> for row in test.splitlines():
...     key, *values = row.split()
...     result[key] = values
... 
>>> result
{'ENSG1': ['1:24', '2:56', '3:47', '4:68', '5:89'], 'ENSG2': ['1:25', '2:57', '3:48', '4:69', '5:90'], 'ENSG3': ['1:26', '2:58', '3:49', '4:70', '5:91']}
```

Comment: Thanks @Delirious Lettuce I am  getting an error "Value Error: Too many values to unpack"  can be help me how to clear this error

Comment: Can u pls explain me the purpose of the " * " near the values and also why is the split command used

Comment: The end result is what I actually I want and  use the key values to call the  corresponding arrays into a new file

Comment: @LakshmiKrishnaKumaar It might be easier to show you with an example: https://bpaste.net/show/a84a6b270ce4  Here is a PEP about unpacking too: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and guidance

Answer (score 0):

Your specific example is answered above by @Delirious Lettuce, However the title of the question : Can a dictionary key be a list element, needs further clarifying.

a list is a mutable object, If you change the list indexes it will not reflect in the dictionary keys. Python will create the key upon assignment and will not point at the original index.

### From the Python Data model documentation:

> The only types of values not acceptable as keys are values containing lists or dictionaries or other mutable types that are compared by value rather than by object identity, the reason being that the efficient implementation of dictionaries requires a key’s hash value to remain constant. Numeric types used for keys obey the normal rules for numeric comparison: if two numbers compare equal (e.g., 1 and 1.0) then they can be used interchangeably to index the same dictionary entry,